Write incremental load data from multiple DynamoDB tables to single S3 bucket
I am working on use case where I need to transfer data from multiple DynamoDB tales to single S3 bucket in an event based manner. The design I had can support data from one DynamoDB table to s3 and is event based architecture. The design is DynamoDB -> DB stream -> Lambda -> SQS -> Lambda -> firehose -> S3. I'll have to transform data in between hence the lambda from SQS to firehose.
Can I use this single pipeline to send data from multiple DynamoDB to single s3 or would have to create multiple same pipeline for each table?
if I can optimize the current design?

Seems complex. But you can use the same pipeline for all tables.
Why not DynamoDB - Kinesis Data Stremas - Firehose - Firehose Transformer - S3
This simplifies the logic and you can use a single stream for all your tables.

I am not consuming real-time stream data, data would be more ad-hoc basis but need it in event driven manner. With kinesis stream, it would be constant polling, overkill and cost wise burden. So came up with this approach.DynamoDB -> DB stream -> Lambda -> SQS -> Lambda -> firehose -> S3, how would this be able to handle multiple dynamoDB to single s3 as sqs won't be grouping based on source name and firehose can group, buffer and write data in particular path? If possible, can you explain the flow?

would you still suggest kinesis stream approach over my approach based on the use case that I mentioned?

If it's not real time then don't stream at all. Just use IncrementalExport to S3.

I need data to be readily available in s3 once they are ingested into DynamoDB tables, so event based

That's realtime. As soon as your data hits DynamoDB you want it available in S3 as soon as possible or "near real time". My suggestion is less complex, more performant and more cost efficient.
